# Resolution complex integral with Matlab

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, bessel-functions

I'm trying to solve an equation proposed by a paper. I can't integrate up to infinite cause the code gives me a warning. I am able to integrate until a value as 2000 or 3000, but the solution differs from the one proposed by the paper (in the paper there is the graphical solution of this equation).Any suggestion? this is the code:

```
Roi=916; 
Row=1024; 

r=50; 
d=50; 
H0=50; 

va=9.46
vi=30.99

b=(H0-vi*vi/(2*9.806))*2
a=(vi/va-1)*(3/2*Roi/Row*b)


N=1000
t=linspace(0,30,N)
for i=1:length(t)
E1=@(x)besselj(0,r/d.*x).*sqrt(x.*tanh(x)).*x.*sin(sqrt(9.81*t(i)^2/d.*x.*tanh(x))).*(sin(a/d.*x)-a./d.*x.*cos(a/d.*x))./(a/d.*x).^3
E(i)= integral(E1,0,inf) 
end


E2=-2*(a^3)/(d^3)*sqrt(2*H0/d-a/d*b/a)/(1+2/3*Row/Roi*a/b)*E*d;
max(E2)

plot(t,E2)
```

Comment: Please use MathJax. What is the function, the integration range and the expected result (say, for one specific choice of the parameter values)?

Comment: Are you sure about the function you're trying to integrate? Could you please add a link to the paper you refer to?

Comment: Dear all, I m sorry but I am not able to use MathJax. Find the paper attached. I'm trying to solve Eq. 20 (Pag.110) where B=[sin(ax/d)-ax/dcos(ax/d)]/(ax/d)^3. The solution of this Eq. is shown in Fig. 6, for some input parameters (please use a and b proposed by me, even though they differ with the one proposed by the paper). I'm not fully sure that the solution proposed by the paper is right, anyway I'd need to prove it. Please do not hesitate to ask me more explanetions. The paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0078323413500054

Comment: Matlab's `integral` uses some default numeric integration method that may not be efficient or accurate for this particular function. You might want to try another method such as `quadl`, see its [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadl.html) for some discussion.

Comment: Hi @Nir! I tried `quadl` but the result is the same.

Comment: Also, where did you get our expression for B? What is given in Eq. 17 of the paper is different.

Comment: @Nir the expression of B was found as the analytical solution of Eq.(22) in the paper.

Comment: You're right that it is an equivalent expression. I wonder why the authors didn't include it. Anyway, your code executes for me in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). So you could try that.

Comment: Good thanks! At this point I m not fully sure that the solution proposed by the paper is right, but anyway I would justify why.